# Hwo to convert array into Comma Saperated string in python?

Tags: python

I Have following Array in python,

```
   [4,5,6]
```

i want my output as
 `['4','5','6']`

How to Do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?.. There are many ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

Use map to convert list of integer to list string:

```
arr = [4,5,6]    
arr = list(map(str,arr))
arr
```

Result :

```
['4', '5', '6']
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want your integers represented as strings, so i suggest a list comprehension:

```
alpha = [4,5,6]
alpha = [str(i) for i in alpha]
print(alpha)
```

Output:

```
['4', '5', '6']
```